# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get the InnerHtml of a child of a child of an element. Here is what I have:

```
If doc.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_FriendsBubble") IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim el As HtmlElement = doc.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_FriendsBubble")
                    inboxTxt.Text = el.Children(1).Children(0).InnerHtml.ToString
                End If
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: When I removed the "Try" function, the error was shown here:

```
If doc.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_FriendsBubble") IsNot Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the assumption that your `doc` object has a value. Try checking if it is nothing also, before you check for child elements.

```
If Not IsNothing(doc) Then
    If Not IsNothing(doc.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_FriendsBubble")) Then
        Dim el As HtmlElement = doc.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_FriendsBubble")
        inboxTxt.Text = el.Children(1).Children(0).InnerHtml.ToString
    End If
End If
```

---

Updated Code. This Works but does not return your `HtmlElement`

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        wb.Navigate("http://www.roblox.com/user.aspx?id=3659905")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = wb.Document
        If Not IsNothing(doc) Then
            Dim el As HtmlElement = doc.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_FriendsBubble")
            If el IsNot Nothing Then
                inboxTxt.Text = el.Children(1).Children(0).InnerHtml.ToString
            Else
                inboxTxt.Text = "No Data"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but now I'm receiving `"Specified cast is not valid."`. How would I fix that now?

Comment: I removed the Try function again. It says it's appearing at `Dim doc As HtmlDocument = wb.Document`

Comment: I replaced `doc` with `wb.Document` where `doc` was being used. It's still coming up with the error.

Comment: I figured the error's appearing wherever `wb.Document` appears. If I move `Dim doc As HtmlDocument = wb.Document` below `If Not IsNothing(wb.Document) Then` then `If Not IsNothing(wb.Document) Then` errors, if I put `Dim doc As HtmlDocument = wb.Document` above `If Not IsNothing(wb.Document) Then` then `If Not IsNothing(wb.Document) Then` errors. :S

Comment: @3659905 That should not cause an issue because the Webbrowser.Document is a HtmlDocument. Try putting a breakpoint on that line and see what the Type of wb.Document is.

Comment: @3659905 what is the URL you are trying to navigate to?

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in but how do I find out what the type is?

Comment: Oh. I fixed it. Made a new `Public Sub` and used `AddHandler` to direct to the `Sub` when `wb.DocumentCompleted`. Thanks for your help =]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, at least one of the expressions `el.Children(1)`, `el.Children(1).Children(0)`, or `el.Children(1).Children(0).InnerHtml` results in null/Nothing. Check each of those, in order, to make sure you actually have a value.

Comment: In that case your `doc` object is Nothing. Check where you assign that variable.